# What is the purpose of creating "Mappings" in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

See the code below:

```
Mappings:
    RegionMap:
        us-east-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-us-east-1
        us-east-2:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-us-east-2
        us-west-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-us-west-1
        us-west-2:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-us-west-2
        ap-south-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-south-1
        ap-northeast-2:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-northeast-2
        ap-southeast-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-southeast-1
        ap-southeast-2:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-southeast-2
        ap-northeast-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-northeast-1
        ca-central-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ca-central-1
        eu-central-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-central-1
        eu-west-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-west-1
        eu-west-2:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-west-2
        eu-west-3:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-west-3
        eu-north-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-north-1
        sa-east-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-east-1
        af-south-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-south-1
        ap-east-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-east-1
        ap-northeast-3:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-ap-northeast-3
        eu-south-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-eu-south-1
        me-south-1:
            bucketname: s3bucketname-me-south-1

Resources:
    StateS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
            BucketName: !Sub "cfntf-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}"
```

There is more to this code however I've only included the relevant snippets for the question.

To summarize - why include mappings for bucketname when the bucketname  is set directly, using region and account ID in the 'Resources' section?

There is use of the `Fn::FindInMap` function which is used here as part of the `ExecutorLambdaFunction`:

```
ExecutorLambdaFunction:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: myfunction
            Handler: index.handler
            Role: !GetAtt ExecutorLambdaServiceRole.Arn
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    BUCKET: !Ref StateS3Bucket
            Code:
                S3Bucket: !If
                  - S3Defined
                  - !Ref S3Bucket
                  - Fn::FindInMap:
                      - RegionMap
                      - !Ref AWS::Region
                      - bucketname
                S3Key: !If
                  - S3Defined
                  - !Ref S3Key
                  - /app.zip
            Runtime: python3.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StateS3Bucket` is being built from the region and account ID but that has *nothing* to do with the `Mappings` section.

The mappings, in this case, are being used to provide the correct region-specific S3 bucket name for where the packaged source code for `ExecutorLambdaFunction` exists - that is why `Fn::FindInMap` is being used in the Lambda declaration.

---

Sometimes you may want to have dynamic values based on specific keys - the CloudFormation [`Mappings`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) section is the perfect solution to this problem.

Your packaged Lambda (the source code) is pointing to an S3 location in this case & as S3 buckets are region-specific, you need a way of getting the *correct* bucket name for the region that the stack is being deployed in.

The code for the `ExecutorLambdaFunction` **must be loaded from the S3 bucket in the relevant region** otherwise it won't work.

For example, trying to load the Lambda source code from a bucket in `us-east-1` won't work when your Lambda is deployed in `eu-west-2` *(note: it will work if it is deployed in `us-east-2` as while that is in another availability zone, it is still within the same region)*.

Even if you only intend to have your stack in one region only, it won't harm you to have a `Mappings` section as it will future proof your CloudFormation template.

If you don't have any region-specific infrastructure (quite rare but e.g. only creating IAM roles which are global & are set at an account-level), then you can not include one.

You'll spend much more time trying to add one in later than if you just spent an extra 3 minutes defining & using `Mappings` as you write your template - you'll thank yourself if you later decide to deploy your stack in another region.

Comment: So, there were other regions however I omitted them due to clarity. Does that mean the mappings overwrite the name which is set directly?

Comment: Ah, that massively changes the narrative - is `FindInMap` used anywhere in your template? It's not an overwrite - it's more like a dictionary lookup

Comment: Please add it in the question and I'll reformat - also please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it'll save everyone tons of time :) once you've updated, I can update my answer relative to your code snippet

Comment: OK thank you, It's a bit tricky to reproduce this code as there are so many dependencies, however I've now added it in a more concise way.

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i I'd recommend also adding the different region values

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i Answer updated - does that help?

Comment: I'll have a look later and let you know, thank you! :)